# Obtaining a 2nd tourist visa for Russia after first expired

Tags: visas, russia, mongolia, tourist-visas, german-citizens

I'm holding a double-entry 30 day tourist visa for Russia which I obtained as a tourist in Japan through the consulate in Osaka. I'm planning to enter Russia, then Mongolia and Russia a 2nd time before going into Kazakhstan.

The 30 days may not be enough to finish the trip and I'm trying to find out if it's possible for me to obtain a 2nd tourist visa from the embassy in Ulaanbaatar, Mongolia.

I know that visas are always issued on an individual basis but was wondering if anyone has experience with it or if there is a rule that forbids it in general. I may need to let my 1st visa be invalidated if it's still running, I assume.

Comment: Why do you believe it's a problem?  Have you tried applying for a Russian visa?  What exactly is your alternative?  And lastly what is your citizenship?

Comment: As the 1st sentence says, I do have a visa right now, I'm German, the alternative is hoping I can make it in 30 days, I believe it could be a problem because some countries do not allow people to enter right again after they outstayed a visa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem.  According to the page on the [Russian Embassy in Ulaanbaatar](http://www.mongolia.mid.ru/en/cons_visa.html) in order for you to obtain a Russian visa there:

> To apply for any category of visas except transit, one must have a long-term registration in Mongolia (“Alien registration card” valid for 1 year).

There are exceptions in the following 2 paragraphs for various countries that do not require to have a registration but Germany unfortunately isn't one of them.

So yes you may be able to obtain another visa following the one you already have just not in Mongolia.

Comment: Thank you, as it says I can get a transit visa which is valid for 10 days. That would be enough for me.

Comment: Conclusion: I was able to obtain transit visas directly from the embassy without problems in Mongolia as well as in Kazakhstan.